# All in one compiler

Tags: codeblocks, sublime-text-plugin

So guys I just finished an intro to c class and learned I really like programming. We used Codeblocks for the course, I branched off and used Sublime code when I was learning HTML CSS and PYTHON on my own. My question is sublime text doesn't compile does it? It's just an editor right? I'm looking for a compiler editor and debugger like code blocks but with a much prettier non windows 98 look. (I don't mind paying for one) I love the style of sublime but I also love the functionality of code blocks. Is there one that can do all this together? I'm running off a windows 10 desktop. I also have a mac for school but everything is primarily done on the windows pc. Any hep would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The term you're looking for is "IDE" btw. And software recommendations are offtopic here. Just google "c ide".

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio is really good for Python and C-based Languages. As for HTML and CSS they don't require compiling so you're all good just with a text editor for those, although Brackets is a good live preview alternative.